# Image centered in Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: image, alignment

This is a very simple html page and I can't figure it out. I just started learning html and I'm having difficulty. Can you please test the site on your Mac? I also tested the site with other devices view and it seems not appearing at all but is perfectly working on my windows 7 and LG magma. My site is: http://kensingtontuition.co.uk/

Thank you very much. This is my first post after joining the last couple of months.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try with Safari for windows (http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe).

And pay attention if you use webkit (CSS) because work only on chrome